# Clearing graphics and Movieclip from sprite - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, sprite

OK I've finally managed to create this piechart which contains drawn graphic segments with a movieclip positioned behind it. The values and size change when you click right and left.

The graphic is reloaded on enter frame so it updates when the values update. I have tried to clear graphics but that has had no affect and now I have everything working except the image is repeatedly loaded on top of itself. I realise my sprite has 2 children in it but haven't succesfully targeted and cleared the parent.. here is the part of the code that created the pie chart...

```
this.graphics.clear();


        drawings.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFFFFFF);
        drawings.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.2);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1start, wedge1end, 0x000000);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1end, wedge2end);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge2end, wedge3end);
        this.drawSegment(drawings, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge3end, wedge4end);
        drawings.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(drawings);



        this.addChild(coin);
        coin.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
        coin.y=stage.stageHeight/2;

        coin.scaleX = piesize / 140;
        coin.scaleY = piesize / 140;

        this.swapChildren(drawings, coin); // swaps two objects
```

Thanks for any advice..

Comment: This code is not relevant to your problem. Please post the code that works per frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the graphics in the 'drawings' object, ie:

```
drawings.graphics.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I've tried so many combinations I'm going mad!

Comment: @bboybeatle Then go sleep some, maybe this will help. Seriously, mindless trial and error costs too much time and energy, and results in so little.

Comment: What you're doing in the example above is definitely not right. You need to .clear graphics from the object into which they were drawn. Where does the drawSegment method draw the graphics?